# Handling events in HtmlHelperClass

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, event-handling, html-helper

USING : **ASP .NET MVC 4.0**, **vs2010**

I have searched internet all the possible ways. But did not find any effective way to handle events in htmlhelperclass.

in server control, i can use events easily. **button_click**, **listbox.SelectedIndexChanged** and many more like them.

without using JS/ jquery, how can i easily handle events of my control with c#? Any reference to effective articles or tutorials will be appreciated(again saying, i am using **asp.net MVC 4.0 razor views** and trying to design **forms** with **htmlhelperclass**).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC there is no concept of "Server Side" controls or Events. You must either use a form or ajax to GET or POST information to the server.

In place of Events, you have Controller actions. So for each "button_click" you would POST data to a controller's action.

If you don't use jQuery or JavaScript, the only other way to do this is by using a form element.